# Change the viewport on one specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to make one specific page on my site respond to screen sizes with the viewport meta tag. The viewport meta tag is generated by a php file in the back end.

Currently my viewport tag looks like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=1040"/>
```

I'm using this jQuery to edit the tag:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0');
});
```

In hopes the viewport tag will turn out like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

I don't identify a page in the jQuery because I have a plugin that lets me run scripts on individual pages. To be more specific, my CMS is Wordpress, my themes are Genesis and the Genesis Sandbox, I'm using an SEO by Yoast plugin, as well as Gravity Forms. How would I go about changing the viewport meta to my desired code?

Comment: If you have a script that let's you run code on a specific page. Why not just put the meta tag in there?

Comment: It is script specific, no html unless it's in script tags.

Comment: try: jQuery(head).append("<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>"); and let me know if that works

Comment: I don't know why, but it's not working. I tried putting your provided script in the header and footer, but to no avail. Thank you though for the idea, though, as it seems like a solid solution.

Comment: Made some errors, try this: $(document).ready(function() {
         $("head").append('<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>');
    });

Comment: I put this in: `jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("head").append('<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>');});` -----Still nothin'.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GB68t/ here it is working. Inspect the head element in the outcome frame to try. If it is not working in your website you are doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... simple, but reasonable solution for sites that are heavily coded.

**1. If you are using "meta viewport" tag in "head" then, below script will work.**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0');
})
```

**2. If "meta viewport" tag in "head" is not present then, use the following script.**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("head").append('<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>');
    jQuery('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0');
})
```

> **Note:** Be sure that you are using "jQuery library version 1.6+" in your webpage.

According to me.. It will definitely work. :)